# Need to make a pageview like in the AppStore

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I needed to make something like a page view in my app. We have all seen the one in the app store (Here its showing shooty skies in the screenshot)

[page view http://www.aapstatic.nl/photos/scr/144/42/536269837/ios-9-app-store.png](http://www.aapstatic.nl/photos/scr/144/42/536269837/ios-9-app-store.png)

I would want the best way to implement this. If maybe a library is present I can use it. I want it to autorotate.

Comment: UIScrollview with pagination enabled & NSTimer to adjust contentOffset for autorotate.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no difference between making a normal scroll view. In addtion, you just need auto-scrolling. What you can do is to make use of `NSTimer` and then periodically rotate.